# JavaScript JSON Object Object error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to print out the key and value names from the data below e.g. "Player 1' - 'ball' 'hat' and "Player 2 - 'ball, 'hat'.  So keys have multiple value names but im not sure how i print these out.** I am getting '[object Object]' as a response**. Can someone help me with this understanding please and trying to resolve the matter.

**Data**

```
{
    "Player1": {
        "ball": 1,
        "hat": 2

    },
    "Player2": {
        "ball": 1,
        "hat": 2,
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    var response = data;
    for (key in response){
        alert("key: " + key + "value :" + response[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try using `console.log("key:", key, "value:", response[key])`; it'll allow you to see the objects, regardless of whether you stringify them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify(response[key])` when printing the object.

Comment: But i only want the property names of the value, not the values too e.g. just  "ball", "hat" and not : { ball: 1} etc

Comment: @user2219097 `response[key]` is also an object, so you can use a for each loop (`for (var k in response[key])`) to loop through and prints its keys.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do this in [any modern browser](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys) would be to [use `Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and just join the result into a string, like this:

```
for (key in response){
    alert("key: " + key + " value :" + Object.keys(response[key]).join(' '));
}
```

Result:

> key: Player1 value :ball hat
>      key: Player2 value :ball hat

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/0dkbs8xg/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
    var response = data;
    for (key in response){
        alert("key: " + key + "value :" + JSON.stringify(response[key]));
    }
});
```

or use `response[key].ball, response[key].hat`

Answer (score 1):

The `stringify` function of `JSON` comes to rescue here. Since most internal functions take data parameters as string or sometimes buffer.
Thus you can use the following code:-

```
    var response = {
    "Player1": {
        "ball": 1,
        "hat": 2

    },
    "Player2": {
        "ball": 1,
        "hat": 2,
    }
}

var dataString = JSON.stringify(response);
```

Now use `dataString` for sending and receiving over different calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of printing the content of the object. [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method is used to access player's "items" and get those in array format. **Updated**.

```js
var response = {
    "Player1": {
        "ball": 1,
            "hat": 2

    },
        "Player2": {
        "ball": 1,
            "hat": 2,
    }
};
for (player in response) {

    var items = Object.keys(response[player]);

    var itemText = "";
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        itemText += " '" + items[i] +  "'";
    }

    console.log(player +  " -" + itemText);
    
    //alternative way, suggested by NickCraver
    console.log(player +  " - "+ Object.keys(response[player]).map(function(k) { return '\''+k+'\''; }).join(' ') );
}
```

Comment: If you require quoting of each value, you should checkout `.map()`, like this: `Object.keys(response[key]).map(function(k) { return '\''+k+'\''; }).join(' '));`

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely try to use .map() function in the future - looks very handy indeed :-)